# How do you do output a nested loop of symbols to a label after inputting the number of rows and columns in windows form c#?

Tags: c#, windows-forms-designer

Have an exercise for taking 2 numbers from the user and making the user choose a symbol to be used from a comboBox dropdownlist. For example:
row is 3
column is 4
symbol is $

it would look like a box of $

I could make it work in console form using Console.WriteLine but I just can't with this and I am out of ideas. Last ditch effort was to just put symList in. (symbox is the label, symlist is the symbol)

```
    int row, col;
int myRow = int.Parse(rowNum.Text);
int myCol = int.Parse(colNum.Text);
for (row = 0; row <= myRow; row++)
{
    for (col = 0; col <= myCol; col++)
    {
        symBox.Text = (symList.Text);
    }
}
```

Comment: if row is 3, column is 4 and symbol is $ then what output you expect?

Comment: Do you want 12 times `$` assigned to `symBox.Text`? `3 rows * 4 columns * $ `?

Comment: yes, it would look like a box

Answer (score 1):

In your case, every iteration of for loop is overwriting the previous symbol and because of that at the end `symBox` contains only one symbol i.e `$`.
You need to store every symbol in each iteration. To do that you can use [`StringBuilder`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.stringbuilder?view=net-5.0) class.

Like,

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (row = 0; row < myRow; row++)
{  
   for (col = 0; col < myCol; col++)
      sb.Append(symList.Text);
   sb.Append(" ");  
   //sb.Append(Environment.NewLine); // If you want to store $$$$ on new line.
}
symBox.Text = sb.ToString();  //It will assign $$$$ $$$$ $$$$
```

[.NetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/WQG7WH)

Comment: it says that the line
sb.Append(new String(symList.Text, myCol));
symList.Text cannot be converted from string to char.
Is there an option on the form design to make symList.Text all in char?
I am fairly new to Windows Form and StringBuilder is a new term for me so thank you for the help!

Comment: I get it now! Thanks for the help!

Comment: I fixed the issue related to `StringBuilder` and also added a hyperlink which explains StringBuilder class.

Answer (score 0):

I think the StringBuilder is the best approach, but this is more of what I'd expect to see from a beginner:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (symList.SelectedIndex != -1)
    {
        int row, col;
        if (int.TryParse(rowNum.Text, out row) && int.TryParse(colNum.Text, out col))
        {
            if (row >= 1 && col >= 1)
            {
                string box = "";
                for(int r=1; r<=row; r++)
                {
                    for(int c=1; c<=col; c++)
                    {
                        box = box + symList.SelectedItem.ToString();
                    }
                    box = box + Environment.NewLine;
                }
                symBox.Text = box;
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Both Row and Column must be >= 1 !");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Invalid Row or Column!");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please select a Symbol first!");
    }            
}
```